# Event management in C + +

Tags: c++, sdl

I tried to use event management in C + +,
I joined the SDL library in VS and in my example,

here is my code:

```
#include "SDL/SDL.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    SDL_Surface *ecran = NULL;
    SDL_Event event; /* La variable contenant l'événement */
    int continuer = 1; /* Notre booléen pour la boucle */

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

    ecran = SDL_SetVideoMode(640, 480, 32, SDL_HWSURFACE);
    SDL_WM_SetCaption("Gestion des événements en SDL", NULL);

    while (continuer) /* TANT QUE la variable ne vaut pas 0 */
    {
        SDL_WaitEvent(&event); /* On attend un événement qu'on récupère dans event */
        switch(event.type) /* On teste le type d'événement */
        {
            case SDL_QUIT: /* Si c'est un événement QUITTER */
                continuer = 0; /* On met le booléen à 0, donc la boucle va s'arrêter */
                break;
        }
    }

    SDL_Quit();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

No error in the code but after compiling I got an error:

```
LINK: fatal error LNK1561: entry point must be defined
```

Comment: How are you compiling/linking the program? Are you linking against SDL and SDLmain?

Comment: What compiler, and how do you compile it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the same issue that you have, but I recall looking at this just a day or two ago!:

Quote:

> There's something wrong with your project's settings. Did you actually create a Console Application? I think that you have created a Win32 Project instead of a Console. Do this: 
>   Right click on project name -> Properties -> Expand Linker tab -> System -> SubSystem: make sure that it is Console (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE).
>    Otherwise, re-create the project, but when you create it, make sure that you select Win32 Console Application.

[link](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/179230-fatal-error-lnk1561-entry-point-must-be-defined)

Looks like you have the same issue here...

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, there was something in the SDL which wraps your `main()` function: In the SDL-header, there is a line

```
#define main some_other_name
```

and then, somewhere in the library, there is a `main()` implementation, which calls `some_other_name()`.

If I read the symptoms correctly, you are not statically linking the sdl library, so that the linker does not see the `main()` definition inside SDL, only the function `some_other_name()` which you have defined.